# How to delete documents from MongoDB using spark scala

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

Is there any way to delete a documents in collection from mongoDB using spark scala since integration done with kafka for steaming data with insert and update the documents to MongoDB but there no way to delete the in case I received a delete transaction from kafka

Comment: Well, what happens when you try to insert/update a documentId with a null value?

Comment: Mongodb is schema less so that provide flexibility to accept any data shape so the null record will be in mongodb a document has just _id field

Comment: Sure. I only know how the Kafka Connector from Mongo manages to delete data, and that is with a null value. You could use that instead of Spark